# Query node's result status in Akka Stream postStop

Tags: scala, akka-stream

In an Akka Stream `GraphStageLogic`'s `postStop`, is there a way to determine whether the stage has failed or completed without error? E.g. get a `Try[Unit]`, that would be a `Failure` if `failStage` had been called or a `Success` if `completeStage` had been called.

- `failStage` is a `final` method, so there is no way to hook into it
- the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.10/scala/stream/stream-error.html) also doesn't say anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is *not*. So you need to monitor all of the node's own calls to `completeStage`, including inlet/outlet handlers.